# Mapping keys in hash - if, exists, map

Tags: perl, if-statement, hash, dictionary, hash-of-hashes

I'm trying to compare the contents of a file with a Hash of hashes. For this I am using `map`, `if` and `exists`, though ineffectively yet.

Basically, I want to know **if columns 0 to 2 of the file exist in a hash**. If so, then I want to find whether **column 3 exists as key in the inner hash**. My "old file.txt" is a tab separated file from which I produce the following hash:

old file.txt:

```
A    s.av    u
B    s.bv    u
C    s.av    u
C    s.cv    m
```

Hash:

```
my %oldhash = {
  'A' => {'s.av' => ['u']},
  'B' => {'s.bv' => ['u']},
  'C' => {'s.av' => ['u'], 's.cv' => ['m']},
};
```

Look if the following tab-separated columns from "new file.txt" exist in the hash:

```
D    Db    Dc    s.av   #cols 0 - 2 do not exist in hash
E    A     Ab    d.ef   #column 1 exists, but column 3 doesn't, so nothing is done
E    A     Ac    s.av   #col 1 and 3 exist, so the new file will have the value of $oldhash{A}{s.av}
B    Bb    B     s.bv   #col0 and 3 exist, so I'll include the value of $oldhash{B}{s.bv}
```

Notice that cols 0 and 2 both exist in the hash, but this is not important since I only need one of the columns to exist.

The output can be exactly as the testing file with an added column that takes `u` or `m` from the other file. Example:

```
D    Db    Dc    s.av       #inserts empty column
E    A     Ab    d.ef       #inserts empty column
E    A     Ac    s.av   u   #with u inserted
B    Bb    B     s.bv   u   #with u inserted
```

This is where I got so far, but I'm getting a `exists argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element or a subroutine at myfile.pl line 24`:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dir='D:\\';

open my $oldfile, "<", "$dir\\old file.txt";
open my $newfile, "<", "$dir\\new file.txt";

my (%oldhash);

# creates the hash of hashes
while (my $odata = <$oldfile>){
    chomp $odata;
    my @oline = split /\t/, lc $odata;
    push @{$oldhash{$oline[1]}{$oline[2]}}, $oline[3];
}

# does the comparison between the file and the hash
while (my $newlines = <$newfile>){
    chomp $newlines;
    my @line = split /\t/, $newlines;
    if (exists map {$oldhash{$_}} @line[0..2]) {
        print $oldhash{$_};
    }
}

close $updatedtax;
close $oldtax;
```

I appreciate all the help that you can give me! Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show the contents of `old file.txt`. Your `%oldhash` hash structure is far from ideal for this purpose. Also please show your required output for this data set

Comment: Are you aware that you are opening `old file.txt` with a file handle `$newfile`, and `new file.txt` with a file handle of `$oldfile`, and then you close `$oldtax` and `$updatedtax`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exists` requires a single array or hash element as its parameter. You have passed it a list of scalar values whose origin has been lost once they have gone through `map`.

You *could* write your test as

```
if ( grep { exists $oldhash{$_} }, @line[0..2] ) { ... }
```

but I think there are better ways to write a solution.

I *think* this does what you want, but with the data you've given it outputs just `u` twice. You haven't shown a required output as I requested, so is that right?

I've inverted the keys that you chose for your own `%oldhash` so that a case can be rejected immediately just by checking for the existence of the fourth column (`s.av` etc.) in the hash.

I've also added `use autodie`, as it's *essential* to check whether an `open` has been successful before you go ahead and use data from the file handle, and this avoids checking every case explicity.

Finally I've added `chdir 'D:\\'` so that you don't have to prefix the file names with the path for every `open`.

The output includes the final "comment" column from `new_file.txt` that gave rise to it. I am sure you can alter the `print` statement to give the output that you desire.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Data::Dump;

chdir 'D:\\';

open my $old_fh, '<', 'old_file.txt';

my %old_data;
while (<$old_fh>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;
  $old_data{$fields[1]}{$fields[0]} = $fields[2];
  print "@fields\n";
}
close $old_fh;

open my $new_fh, '<', 'new_file.txt';

while (<$new_fh>) {

  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;

  my $new = '';
  if (my $list = $old_data{$fields[3]}) {
    my @possible = grep defined, @{$list}{@fields[0,1,2]};
    $new = $possible[0] if @possible;
  }

  print join("\t", @fields[0..3], $new, $fields[4]), "\n";
}
```

The contents of `%old_data` after reading the file look like this

```
(
  "s.av" => { A => "u", C => "u" },
  "s.bv" => { B => "u" },
  "s.cv" => { C => "m" },
)
```

**output**

```
D Db  Dc  s.av    #cols 0 - 2 do not exist in hash
E A Ab  d.ef    #column 1 exists, but column 3 doesn't, so nothing is done
E A Ac  s.av  u #col 1 and 3 exist, so the new file will have the value of $oldhash{A}{s.av}
B Bb  B s.bv  u #col0 and 3 exist, so I'll include the value of $oldhash{B}{s.bv}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had missed the output in my post. But I think I can already play around with your answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sosi: I've fixed it to give the output that you request

Comment: @Sosi: Altered slightly to use `grep` instead of a `for` loop for tidiness and clarity

Comment: Thanks! What does `dd \%old_data;` do?

Comment: @Sosi: I'm sorry, that is a legacy from my debugging. It's a function provided by [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) (which IMO is highly superior to `Data::Dumper` because its output is so much more readable). It simply dumps the hash to the current file handle, and I used it to create the dump that I included in my answer. I've removed it.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'll also have a look at `Data::Dump`, good thing you forgot about it there

Comment: a couple of comments: 1.the final printing line should be `print join("\t", @fields[0..2], $new, $fields[3]), "\n";` (note the argument of `$fields`); 2. the output that I get is a ref to an array corresponding to `$new`. If I print instead `print join("\t", @fields[0..3], @{$new}, $fields[4]), "\n";` I get errors when $new is undefined. How could I solve this?

Comment: ok, finally changing `$new` to `$new = [''];` and the print to `print join("\t", @fields[0..2], @{$new}, $fields[3]), "\n";` solves these problems

Comment: @Sosi: You are wrong in both of your comments. My `print` statement prints the first four fields from `new_file.txt`, followed by the matching value from `old_file.txt`, followed by the last (comment) field from `new_file.txt`. If you do as you describe then you will get, for example, `E    A     Ac    u    s.av`. What do you mean by *"the output that I get is a ref to an array "*? The only output is a tab-separated text file. And `$new` is *never* undefined: it is initialised to the empty string `''`.

Comment: @Sosi: Please raise a new question showing what you have done to break this solution. Perhaps on [Stack Echange's *Code Review* site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I was having those errors that I posted above when trying to implement your code in my example. It may have been something that was slightly different in my example and/or in the way I translated your answer to my real example. Either way, your code works for the working example that I showed, so kudos! Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question (and I'm sorry for extending these comments further) but why are you dereferencing `$list` into an array in `@{$list}{@fields[0,1,2]}` if `$list` is a ref to a hash?

Comment: That is a hash *slice*. Elements `a`, `b` and `c` of hash `%data` are `($data{a}, $data{b}, $data{c})` or `@data{qw/ a b c /}`. The '@` sigil is saying that the expresion is a *list*, whereas the `$` sigil in `$hash{a}` says that the expression is a *scalar*. Incientally, that is why you get a warning if you write `@array[1]` instead of `$array[1]`, but `@array[1,2,3]` is correct

Comment: Thank you so much, you don't know how much I learnt from this thread. Thank you!